# Is it possible to screen record on Google Glass without a Computer?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I want to video record the screen of an application I made on Google Glass.

I've seen this link here: http://googleglassfans.com/archives/3814/record-google-glass-screen-using-adb/
that uses the screenrecord function along with command prompt to get a video but I wanted to see if it was possible to do that without hooking it up to a computer. No audio is necessary just the video. I'm new to programming with google glass so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Any help as to whether it is and if so how to learn how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is possible. If you can screenrecord on android, you can screenrecord on Glass

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you know of any links or places I read on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Running `screenrecord` requires a connected computer that has the `adb` command available. It is not possible to run this particular command without a connected computer.

The rest of my answer is not specific but will hopefully be able to guide you in the right direction.

There are a lot of open source projects on GitHub or elsewhere catering to capturing screen activity on Android. You may want to look at using those. However, they may have permission requirements (in the Android manifest sense) that are not allowed on Google Glass (see [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/permissions) for allowed permissions). Because of this, this solution *may* require you to root your Glass device and thus void your warranty.

If you are fine with voiding your warranty, this is one option for you.